# It is possible turn off vim plugin while editing?

Tags: vim

I have a slow plugin with a very useful feature. Maybe possible turn on/off this plugin while editing?

Comment: Perhaps, better to ask the plugin developer. Have try plugins forum/mailing list?

Comment: yes, it is https://github.com/Quramy/tsuquyomi